# Use of "ею" instead of "ей" in instrumental

Tags: грамматика, падежи

My grammar book states (as quoted below) that **ею** is preferred to **ей** in the instrumental case for educated speech. Is it worth using this form in everyday speech?

Я слежу за нею.

Дракон летит над нею.

и тд

And as a side note, when should (can) I use тобою, моею and all the other similar forms?

---

> (c) The alternative instrumental form of она́ (**е́ю**) is preferred to **ей** in educated speech and is particularly important in passive constructions, avoiding possible confusion with the dative:
>
> Револю́цией перестро́йку мо́жно назва́ть в си́лу радика́льности поста́вленных **е́ю** це́лей (*Izvestiya*)
> Restructuring can be called a revolution by virtue of the radical nature of the goals set **by it**
>
> (**Ей** would imply a dative meaning: 'the goals set **for** it'.)
>
> (2) The oblique cases of **он**, **она́**, **оно́**, **они́** take initial **н-** when governed by a preposition: от **н**его́ 'from him', к **н**ей 'to her', с **н**и́ми 'with them' etc.  However, some *compound* prepositions take a third-person pronoun *without* initial **н-**. They include:
>
> (i) A number of derivative prepositions governing the dative: благадаря́ **им** 'thanks to them', **ему́** навстре́чу 'to meet him',  на зло **ей** ' to spite her'.  Others include **вопреки́** 'contrary to', **напереко́р** 'counter to', **подо́бно** 'similar to', **согла́сно** 'in accordance with'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rationale behind recommending **ею** is that **ей** is easily confused with the dative. Nothing else has this problem, and it's already gone when using the form with a preposition. The dative only governs two prepositions, **к** and **по**, and both are exclusive to it. So the **ней** forms following prepositions are never ambiguous (yes, it's also the prepositional case form, but no prepositions overlap with the instrumental there either), and there's no particular reason to use **нею**.

Generally, the instrumental in `-ю` sounds archaic/poetic, and with literally everything except **ею**, they're not something a person would use nowadays unless they're deliberately trying to come across as either affected or facetious.

(I might just add that none of this applies to the 3rd-declension noun instrumental `-ью`, where the `ю` never goes away. That said, it is itself a contraction of the older `-ию` — *мыслию*, *совестию* — which is even more distinctly archaic than the `-ою`/`-ею` on 1st declension nouns, adjectives, and pronouns.)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not preferred for educated speech, the standard form is "ей". "Ею" sounds either uneducated(country-style) or archaic.

Comment: Well, he disagrees

https://www.google.ru/imgres?imgurl=http://t2.gstatic.com/images%3Fq%3Dtbn:ANd9GcTGhlj1htRwj7b_gKMnozLLyBsmNXnP0AUAKQd3tqt1G_lnD9ww&imgrefurl=http://books.google.com/books/about/A_Comprehensive_Russian_Grammar.html%3Fid%3DxltIrGHlMDQC%26source%3Dkp_cover&h=900&w=625&tbnid=jrS32ZDaQpHqJM:&tbnh=160&tbnw=110&docid=ctfdduhHSjEM1M&itg=1&client=safari&usg=__ZW616vd5nzQRIsMfFjCA75hzpfk=

It's what Nikolay mentioned. The instrumental looks like the dative in passive constructions, so that's were ею can be used. I just didn't get that at first when I read in the book.

Comment: @VCH250 it can be used in fringe cases (maybe, I never encountered this) but it looks strange, archaic and/or country-style.

Comment: That's literally the opposite of what every "educated speech" authority out there says. http://thedifference.ru/kak-pishetsya-pravilno-ej-ili-eyu/ I don't personally think there's anything wrong with `ей` unless there's true ambiguity, but actually claiming that `ей` is *preferred* is the same kind of uninformed (or revisionist) folk prescriptivism as the dot-your-Ёs movement.

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov ею is just wrong if school education concerned.

Comment: @Anixx Any sources?

Comment: @ Anixx I added my source 
@ Nikolay Ershov (same)